# Expected value of $\bar x^2$ shows different values when calculating through different equations.

Tags: statistics, variance, standard-deviation, data-analysis

Here are the basic notations:

Population mean = $\mu$

Sample mean = $\bar x$

Population variance = $\sigma^2$

E = Estimator

Assumption $E(x_i) = \mu$

$E(x_i)$ is any random variable within the population space.

$$E(\bar x) = E(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i)$$
$$E(\bar x) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n E(x_i)$$
$$E(\bar x) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \mu$$
$$E(\bar x) = \frac{1}{n}. n. \mu$$
$$E(\bar x) = \mu$$

Now,

$$Var(x_i) = E(x_i^2) - (E(x_i)^2)$$
$$\sigma^2 = E(x_i^2) - \mu^2$$
$$ E(x_i^2)= \mu^2 + \sigma^2 $$
$ E(x_i^2)= \mu^2 + \sigma^2 $ Let this be equation 1

Also,

$$var(\bar x) = E(\bar x^2)-(E(\bar x))^2$$
$$E(\bar x^2) = \frac{\sigma^2}{n} + \mu^2$$
$E(\bar x^2) = \frac{\sigma^2}{n} + \mu^2$ Let this be equation 2

Also using the Estimator,

$$E(\bar x^2) = E(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i)^2$$
$$E(\bar x^2) = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n E(x_i)^2$$

From equation 1 we know that $ E(x_i^2)= \mu^2 + \sigma^2 $
Hence,

$$E(\bar x^2) = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n (\sigma^2+\mu^2)$$
$$E(\bar x^2) = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n (\sigma^2+\mu^2)$$
$$E(\bar x^2) = \frac{1}{n^2} .n^2. (\sigma^2+\mu^2)$$
$$E(\bar x^2) = (\sigma^2+\mu^2)$$

How can $E(\bar x^2)$ have two values as shown above and equation 2 Where $E(\bar x^2) = \frac {\sigma^2}{n} + \mu^2$

Comment: $E\left[\overline x^2\right]=E\left[ \left(\frac 1n \sum x_i\right)^2\right]$ which is not the same as as $\left(E\left[ \frac 1n \sum x_i\right]\right)^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line after "Also using the Estimator" is incorrect.

It should be

$$E(\bar x^2) = E\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2\right) = E\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)\right)$$

This isn't equal to

$$E\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right)$$

Particularly because you will get terms like $x_i x_j$, where $i \ne j$ in the first case, which you wouldn't get in the second case.

Everything before this line seems correct though; but everything after this line that uses the equation after "Also using the Estimator" is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks that was a stupid mistake on my part. Also is there a way of solving it by expressing $\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=j+1}^n x_i.x_j$ in terms of $\sigma^2$ and $\mu$?

Comment: @RohitKrishnan  when $i\not =j$ you have $x_i$ and $x_j$ independent so  $E[x_ix_j] = E[x_i]E[x_j] = \mu^2$

Comment: Yes. And otherwise unfortuantely the only thing you can rely on is the definition of expectation. For discrete varaibles $E(x_i x_j) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} k\ \mathbb{P}(x_i x_j = k)$